# D3 markers are not displayed proberly on Firefox but on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, d3.js, marker

I have a problem with a D3 graph. On Firefox the markers are not shown. On Chrome they are shown.

This is a working example we it is working on both: https://jsfiddle.net/ztqt2au0/20/

I can't find the answer what may prevent the markers to be shown. Any ideas?

HTML-Code:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container">
<div id="sidebar" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item-group">
        <label class="item-label">Filter</label>
        <div id="filterContainer" class="filterContainer checkbox-interaction-group"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="graphContainer" class="graphContainer"></div>
</div>
```

JS-Code:

```
// method to get page height
function pageHeight() {
    var lReturn = window.innerHeight;
    if (typeof lReturn == "undefined") {
        if (typeof document.documentElement != "undefined" && typeof document.documentElement.clientHeight != "undefined") {
            lReturn = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (typeof document.body != "undefined") {
            lReturn = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
    }
    return lReturn;
}

// method to get page width
function pageWidth() {
    var lReturn = window.innerWidth;
    if (typeof lReturn == "undefined") {
        if (typeof document.documentElement != "undefined" && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != "undefined") {
            lReturn = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        } else if (typeof document.body != "undefined") {
            lReturn = document.body.clientWidth;
        }
    }
    return lReturn;
}

// Create Graph using d3.js force-directed layout
$(function () {
    var links = [
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "client_vendor"},
        {source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "client_vendor"}
    ];

        var nodes = {};

    var w = pageWidth() - 10,
        h = pageHeight() - 10;

        // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
        links.forEach(function(link) {
          link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
          link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

        var force = d3.layout.force()
                .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
                .links(links)
                .size([w, h])
                .linkDistance(200)
                .charge(-1000)
                .on("tick", tick)
                .start();
        var drag = force.drag()
            .on("dragstart", dragstart);



        var svg = d3.select("#graphContainer").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
            .append("g");


        // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
        svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")

          .data(["client_vendor", "acquired", "flagship", "merged", "parent_sub", "plaintiff_def", "shareholder_of", "sold", "spin_off_from", "supplies_to", "has_supplier"])     // Defines which type should have marker

          .enter().append("svg:marker")
            .attr("id", String)
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
          .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

        var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type+"_"+d.status; })
            .style("marker-end", function(d) { return "url('#" + d.type + "')"; }) ;


        var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return "id_"+(d.index);})
            .attr("special", function(d) {
                if (d.name === $('#tab_graph_company_select_company').val()) {
                    return "centerNode";
                }
            })
            .on("click", nodeclick)
            .call(drag);
//       
        circle.append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
                .size(200)
                .type(function(d) { 
                    if (d.isAgcs) {
                        return 'diamond';
                    } else {
                        return d3.svg.symbolTypes[0];
                    }
                    }))

            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                if (typeof d.color !== 'undefined' && d.color !== null && d.color !== "") {
                    return d.color;
                } else {
                    return "grey";
                }
              })
              ;
        var textNode = circle.append("g");


        if (true) {
            // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
            textNode.append("svg:text")
                .attr("dx", 12)
                .attr("dy", ".31em")
                .text(function(d) { 
                    return d.name; 
                    });

        }

        // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
        function tick() {
          path.attr("d", function(d) {

            if (d.linknum === 1) {
                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            } else {

                var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                    dr = 1000/1;  //linknum is defined above
                return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " " +0+ " " +0+","+1+" " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
            }

          });

          circle.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

        } // End: function tick ()

        var k = 0;
        while ((force.alpha() > 1e-2) && (k < 150)) {
            force.tick(),
            k = k + 1;
            if (k == 149) {
                console.log('trying to fix center node');

            }
        }

        function nodeclick(d) {
            if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
            console.log('clicked');
        }

        function dragstart(d) {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
            console.log('dragged');
            d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
        }


        function zoom() {
            var zoom = d3.event;
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + zoom.translate + ")scale(" + zoom.scale + ")");
        }
        });


var graphView = {
        showProperties : function(d3NodeObject, node) {

        },

        unfixNode : function() {
            d3Object.classed("fixed", selectedNode.fixed = false);
        },

        fixNode : function() {
            d3Object.classed("fixed", selectedNode.fixed = true);
        },

        refocus : function(event) {

        },

        fixCenterNode : function(d3NodeObject) {
        },

        selectedNode : null,
        d3Object : null,

        defaultRadius : 1000,
        xAxisRotation : 0,
        largeArcFlag : 0, //  '1', then one of the two larger arc sweeps  will be chosen; otherwise, if large-arc-flag is '0', one of the smaller arc sweeps will be chosen,
        sweepFlag : 1, //  '1', then the arc will be drawn in a "positive-angle"  direction. A value of 0 causes the arc to be drawn in a "negative-angle"  direction.
        charge : -1000,
        linkDistance : 200,
        showText : true
    }
```

CSS-Code:

```
body {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
          path.link {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #666;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
            marker#client_vendor {
                fill: green;
            }

            path.link.client_vendor {
              stroke: green;
            }

            marker#acquired {
                fill: blue;
            }
            path.link.acquired {
              stroke: blue;
            }               

            marker#competitor {
                fill: red;
            }
            path.link.competitor {
              stroke: red;
            }       

            marker#flagship {
                fill: orange;
            }
            path.link.flagship {
              stroke: orange;
            }

            marker#merged {
                fill: black;
            }
            path.link.merged {
              stroke: black;
            }

            marker#parent_sub {
                fill: green;
            }
            path.link.parent_sub {
              stroke: green;
              stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
            }

            marker#plaintiff_def {
                fill: blue;
            }
            path.link.plaintiff_def {
              stroke: blue;
              stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
            }

            marker#shareholder_of {
                fill: red;
            }
            path.link.shareholder_of {
              stroke: red;
              stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
            }

            marker#sold {
                fill: orange;
            }
            path.link.sold {
              stroke: orange;
              stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
            }

            marker#spin_off_from {
                fill: black;
            }
            path.link.spin_off_from {
              stroke: black;
              stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
            }

            circle {
                cursor: move;
                fill: #ccc;
                stroke: #333;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }

            text {
              font: 10px Verdana, sans-serif;
              pointer-events: none;
              color: black;
            }

            text.shadow {
              stroke: #fff;
              stroke-width: 3px;
              stroke-opacity: .8;
            }
            #networkChart {
                margin-top: -20px;
                margin-left: -40px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the div with the graph from "networkChart_orig" to "networkChart".

```
    <div id="tabs-0">
        <div id="networkChart"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid" >

            <div id="left-panel" class="cd-panel from-left">
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <h1>Settings</h1>
                    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
                </header>

                <div class="cd-panel-container">
                    <div class="cd-panel-content">
                        <div  style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            Provider: 
                            <div id="selectedProvider" class="azfs pulldown max-10" data-snippet-name="pulldown" style="width: 100px">
                                <input type="text" class="pulldown-display" tabindex="-1" value="" placeholder="Choose provider" readonly="readonly" />
                                <a class="pulldown-button" href="javascript;"></a> 
                                <input class="pulldown-value" type="hidden" value="" />
                                <div class="pulldown-values-wrapper" style="top:30px; height: 72px;">
                                    <ul class="pulldown-values">
                                        <li data-value='t1'>t1</li>
                                        <li data-value='t2'>t2</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            No. of Levels:
                            <div id="select_level" class="azfs pulldown max-10" data-snippet-name="pulldown" style="width: 100px">
                                <input type="text" class="pulldown-display" tabindex="-1" value="1" readonly="readonly" />
                                <a class="pulldown-button" href="javascript;"></a> 
                                <input class="pulldown-value" type="hidden" value="1" />
                                <div class="pulldown-values-wrapper" style="top:30px; height: 140px;">
                                    <ul class="pulldown-values">
                                        <li data-value='1'>1</li>
                                        <li data-value='2'>2</li>
                                        <li data-value='3'>3</li>
                                        <li data-value='4'>4</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                 

                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            Company: 
                            <input id="input_graph_company_search" class="azfs input-field" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="" value="" data-snippet-name="input-field" />
                            <a id="button_graph_company_search" href="javascript:;" class="azfs button medium disabled" data-snippet-name="button" tabindex="-1">Search</a>
                            <!--input type="text" id="input_graph_company_search">&nbsp;<button id="button_graph_company_search">Search</button-->
                            <div id="searchSpinner_tabs-0"></div>                                                           
                            <br>
                            <h4>Select Company:</h4>
                            <select disabled id="tab_graph_company_select_company" size="10"><option value="none">-- NONE --</option></select>
                        </div>
                        <div   style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                <h4>Type of Relationship:</h4>
                                                <div class="col-md-12" id="select_relation_type"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
                </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
            </div> <!-- cd-panel -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">  <!-- Begin: Left panel  col-lg-3-->
                    <div class="row"> <!-- Begin: inner row for left panel -->
                        <div id="graphsettings">
                            <a href="#0">Settings</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>  <!-- End: inner row for left panel -->
                </div> <!-- End: Left panel -->         
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> <!-- Begin: Main panel -->
                    <div id="networkChart_orig"></div>
                </div>   <!-- End: Main panel -->
            </div>                                                              
        </div> <!-- Container end -->   
    </div> <!-- End of tabs-0 -->
```

But I do not understand what is the difference. :-(